# Best way to animate the hidden property on a component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I saw in a keynote that in upcoming versions of React, it is wise to hide a component or an element with the property `hidden`. However, I was wondering how you could add an effect onto the transition when e.g. toggling the visibility of an element.

Here a little example. If you drop the `hidden` property, the transition takes place.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isHidden: true
  }
  
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const className = this.state.isHidden ?
      'is-hidden' : 'is-visible';
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>
        <div className={'elm ' + className} hidden={this.state.isHidden}>
          Hello world
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.elm {
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

How can I use the `hidden` property and still use CSS transitions?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `hidden` prop if transitioning opacity does what you like?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure, but I assume that the React property `isHidden` is doing a CSS `display:none;` behind the scenes. You can't transition the display property in CSS.

So if the transition is important, I'd hide the elements with CSS `opacity:0` on load then add the visible class when you're ready.

Comment: So I would effectively need 2 states?

Comment: Well you technically have 2 states now. Its just that the way React is hiding the elements isn't compatible with a transition. You would remove that and create a hidden class that's the default and then swap it out when your happy with the state of the content.